# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'rc', but it was: a custom ac object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

The error happens in this code:

```
document.querySelector('.adding').onclick = async function adding() {

  const output = document.querySelector('.added')
  const translate = collection(db, "translate")
  await setDoc(translate, {
    eng_tot,
    sank_tot
  });
  output.innerText = 'Added'
  console.log('added', english, sanskrit)
  english.value = ''
  sanskrit.value = ''
  eng_tot = []
  sank_tot = []
  setTimeout(() => {
    output.innerText = ''
  }, 2000);
};
```

** I am trying from 2 days but can't understand what's the problem !!**

I am trying to add an array in firebase , i am tring so many solution but can't get what's the problem !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`setDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#setdoc_2) function takes a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) as first parameter but you are passing a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference). If you want to add a document with random ID then use [`addDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#adddoc) instead:

```
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"

const translate = collection(db, "translate")
await addDoc(translate, {
  eng_tot,
  sank_tot
});
```

If you want to specify the document ID yourself, then use `doc()` to create a document reference and then use `setDoc()`:

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"

const translateDoc = doc(db, "translate", "custom_doc_id")
await setDoc(translateDoc, {
  eng_tot,
  sank_tot
});
```